# Data Restatement

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hadoop, join, hive

I have a table named 'old_table' and it is an external table, it has 8 columns, they are name, place, dob, hobby, school, gender, class, details. Here details column is a struct array type, for example it has values like [{age:23, orphan:no, alive:yes, gender:Male, class:6},{age:20, orphan:yes, alive:Yes, gender:female, class:8}, and so on].

Recently we added 2 more fields in this details column that is name and place, so now the structure is [{age:23, orphan:no, alive:yes, gender:Male, class:6, name:raju, place:mumbai},{age:20, orphan:yes, alive:Yes, gender:female, class:8, name:raju, place:mumbai}, and so on].

This table is a partitioned table. We updated the table with these two fields from Jan 7, so I want the old partitions also to be updated with values taking from their respective columns. These 2 fields must take values from those two columns name and place.

I created a new_table with the updated schema, and I copied data from old_table, those 2 fields are null for all the rows now, how to update these values with the values taken from their respective columns? I want a hive query for this and one thing I noticed is when I checked schema for this through hive even for the old partitions, it is showing the updated schema but when I check it through spark, I am getting the old schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert overwrite like this

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE old_table
SELECT
  name,
  place,
  dob,
  hobby,
  school,
  gender,
  class,
  TRANSFORM(details, e -> named_struct('age', e.age, 'orphan', e.orphan, 'alive', e.alive, 'gender', e.gender, 'class', e.class, 'name', name, 'place', place)) as details
FROM old_table;
```

Then you need to repair your table

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE old_table;
```

Why we need

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE:

Partition Discovery:
If you've added or removed partitions manually in HDFS (for example, through external tools or scripts), Hive might not automatically recognize these changes. Running MSCK REPAIR TABLE helps Hive discover and register the new partitions.
Schema Mismatch:
When there's a discrepancy in schema information between Hive and the actual data files in HDFS, running MSCK REPAIR TABLE can help reconcile these differences.
```